# Are there any cases where `x.valueOf() === x` could return `false`?

Tags: javascript, primitive, primitive-types, value-of

I'm trying to understand the `valueOf()` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Is there a situation where a variable of any type could return `false` for the following check ?

`x.valueOf() === x`

```js
const obj = {};
const str = "abc";
const strNum = "123";
const number = 123;
const arrStr = ["a","b","c"];
const arrNum = [1,2,3];

console.log(obj.valueOf() === obj);
console.log(str.valueOf() === str);
console.log(strNum.valueOf() === strNum);
console.log(number.valueOf() === number);
console.log(arrStr.valueOf() === arrStr);
console.log(arrNum.valueOf() === arrNum);
```

Comment: if it's null ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable with a custom `valueOf` method could return a value which fails the test:

```js
const obj = {
  valueOf() {
    return NaN;
  }
};
console.log(obj.valueOf() === obj);
```

A number wrapped in an object would also return false:

```js
const obj = new Number(5);
console.log(obj.valueOf() === obj);
```

The MDN documentation looks misleading. `Object.prototype.valueOf` will return an object or throw an error - see the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.valueof).

Keep in mind that when calling `valueOf` on non-objects, like numbers/strings/booleans, you'll be invoking the `valueOf` method of *that particular primitive* (eg `Number.prototype.valueOf`), rather than `Object.prototype.valueOf`.

Comment: Thanks. But with the standard `valueOf()` method it will be always `true` ?

Comment: @cbdeveloper *if* you're calling the standard one from the Object prototype. That's not at all guaranteed, for example `Object.create(null)` will produce a plain object without a `valueOf` method, since there will be no prototype. So, you'd get an error when calling `noProtoObj.valueOf()`

Comment: @VLAZ thanks! There's still one thing I don't understand: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) : _The valueOf() method returns the **primitive value** of the specified object._. If objects are not primitive values, how can objects are returned from the `valueOf` method? The primitive value of an object is the object itself?

Comment: @cbdeveloper a further paragraph answers that: "*If an object has no primitive value, valueOf returns the object itself.*"

Comment: @VLAZ my bad! Will read the doc more carefully next time! Thanks a lot VLAZ